# Rotate image such that is matches a second image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I would like to rotate an image based on a second image. Both images are satellite images, however, they are not rotated in the same direction(in one image top is in the north direction and in the other the rotation is not known). But, I have at least three pixel pairs in each of the images (x1,y1,x2,y2). So my idea is to figure out their relative position and get the rotation angle from that.

Currently, I estimate the angle like this:

```
def angle_between(v1, v2):
    """ Returns the angle in radians between vectors 'v1' and 'v2'::

            >>> angle_between((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0))
            1.5707963267948966
            >>> angle_between((1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0))
            0.0
            >>> angle_between((1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0))
            3.141592653589793
    """
    v1_u = unit_vector(v1)
    v2_u = unit_vector(v2)
    angle_rad = np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(v1_u, v2_u), -1.0, 1.0))
    return (angle_rad*180)/math.pi
```

with the inputs like this:

```
v1 = [points[0][0] - points[1][0], points[0][1] - points[1][1]] #hist

v2 = [points[0][2] - points[1][2], points[0][3] - points[1][3]] #ref
```

However, this only uses two pixel pairs instead of the three. Therefore, the rotation is some times incorrect. Could anybody show me how to use all three pixels?

My first attempt was to check on which side of the straight the third pixel lies in the image and based on that negate the angle. But, this does not work for all images.

**EDIT**:

I cannot add the original images, as they are copyrighted, however, as the image content is not really important I added whitened images. The first is the input image with the three points drawn in, the second is the rotated image (where additionally the (wrong, due to rotation) cutout area is marked with a rectangle) and third the historical image.

The points are the following:

```
567.01,144,1544.4,4581.8
1182.6,1568.1,2934.1,3724.3
938.97,1398.1,2795.8,4002.5
```

with:

```
x_historical, y_historical, x_presentday, y_presentday
```

[image: Original image]
[image: Original image rotated]
[image: Historical image]

Comment: with 3 pixel pairs (2D) you can compute an affine homography, which includes rotation, translation, scaling, shearing (6 degrees of freedom). Try https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getaffinetransform#getaffinetransform and/or https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform whether it gives acceptable results.

Comment: Option one does not work, as the images are not the same size, thus it not only rotates the image (sorry I didn't specify that). The second option does not work as I am using OpenCV 4.2.0 in which cv2.estimateRigidTransform is depreciated and with cv2.estimateAffine2D the same issue as with option one occures.

Comment: then you can implement your own DLT with just the rotation and rotation center part of the homography.

Comment: can you show sample images and provide sample points?

Comment: I added an example image, with the points